# Calculating the normal force of a car, that's driving on a curved bridge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, rotational-dynamics, rotation

I got a physics assingment, where I must be getting something wrong.

I have been asked to calculate the **normal force** of a car (*m = 1300kg*) (as a simplified point) that's driving at *40km/h* on a curved bridge with a radius of *50 meters*. it is only asked to consider the **middle point** of the bridge, so exaclty when the **gravitational force** is *perpendicular* to the bridge.

This is also kind of the point where I do not quite get it. If the gravitational force is perpendicular to the bridge, how can there be a normal force (note that it is not asked to calculate the normal force from the bridge to the car but the other way around).

Comment: Please copy out the entire question that you were asked, translating it into English if necessary, and add that to your question. As it is, there is not enough information here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is asking for the normal force at the "top" of the bridge, where the gravitational force and the normal force are both aligned in a straight line.  Since the bridge is circular, there has to be a centripetal force that causes the car to travel in a circle, and that force is provided by the force of gravity.  This means that the normal force on the car is less than the car's weight as it travels over the bridge, which can clearly be seen by drawing a free body diagram of the car and setting up the equation for the net force on the car.

Comment: Upvoted, but strictly speaking, we don't know that the bridge is convex upwards rather than downwards because that information is missing from the question. If convex downwards the normal force on the car would be greater than the weight of the car.

Comment: @MatthewChristopherBartsh, granted, but every bridge that I have driven over was convex upwards.  I didn't think of that issue, but I have to assume that if the bridge was convex downward, the author of the question would have stated that.  And thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Any driveable bridge in the real world that was curved and convex downward (concave upward might be a better way to put it, I just realized) would almost certainly be a suspension bridge and they are never part of a circle, but rather a catenary curve.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64HuuBxIzyg at 30 seconds into the video shows a driveable bridge that is concave upward, and, is also a catenary curve (except in a high wind as shown in the video clip).